# select...Case...EndSelect having problems with my code

Tags: bots, autoit

I'm trying to build an automatic answer for a simple math question where the number of total variables in the question depends on the position of the question mark, here are few examples:

```
What is 56 x 3 ?
What is 7 x 3 ?
What is 232 x 634 ?
```

I have created a code but I can't make it work, here is my code

```
#include <AutoItConstants.au3>
HotKeySet("{F4}", "ExitProg")
Func ExitProg()
   Exit 0
EndFunc

MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 417, 659, 2, 1)
Send("^c")

Func valData()
   $Chek = "What "
   If ClipGet() == $Chek Then
      Check()
      Else
      Do
         MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 417, 659, 2, 3)
         Send("^c")
         Sleep(500)
      Until ClipGet() == $Chek

   EndIf
EndFunc

Func Check()
   $Chek2 = "?"

   Select
      Case c1() == $Chek2
      ;two
         cc1()
      Case c2() == $Chek2
      ;three
         cc2()
      Case c3() == $Chek2
      ;four
         cc3()
      Case c4() == $Chek2
      ;five
         cc4()
      Case c5() == $Chek2
      ;six
         cc5()
      Case c6() == $Chek2
      ;seven
         cc6()
      Case c7() == $Chek2
      ;eight
         cc7()
      Case Else
         Exit
   EndSelect
EndFunc

Func c1()
   MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 485, 643, 2, 1)
   Send("^c")
EndFunc

Func c2()
   MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 493, 644, 2, 1)
   Send("^c")
EndFunc

Func c3()
   MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 498, 645, 2, 1)
   Send("^c")
EndFunc

Func c4()
   MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 508, 647, 2, 1)
   Send("^c")
EndFunc

Func c5()
   MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 514, 645, 2, 1)
   Send("^c")
EndFunc

Func c6()
    MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 523, 645, 2, 1)
    Send("^c")
EndFunc

Func c7()
   MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 530, 645, 2, 1)
   Send("^c")
EndFunc

Func cc1()
   MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 453, 645, 2, 1)
   Send("^c")
   Sleep(500)
   MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 1347, 197, 1, 1)
   Send("^v")
   Sleep(500)
   MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 474, 645, 2, 1)
   Send("^c")
   Sleep(500)
   MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 1347, 197, 1, 1)
   Send("*")
   Send("^v")
   Send("{NUMPADENTER}")
EndFunc
Func cc2()
  MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 453, 645, 2, 1)
   Send("^c")
   Sleep(500)
   MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 1347, 197, 1, 1)
   Send("^v")
   SLeep(500)
   MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 482, 645, 2, 1)
   Send("^c")
   Sleep(500)
   MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 1347, 197, 1, 1)
   Send("*")
   Send("^v")
   Send("{NUMPADENTER}")
EndFunc
Func cc3()
   MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 453, 645, 2, 1)
   Send("^c")
   Sleep(500)
   MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 1347, 197, 1, 1)
   Send("^v")
   Sleep(500)
   MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 487, 645, 2, 1)
   Send("^c")
   Sleep(500)
   MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 1347, 197, 1, 1)
   Send("*")
   Send("^v")
   Send("{NUMPADENTER}")
EndFunc
Func cc4()
   MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 453, 645, 2, 1)
   Send("^c")
   Sleep(500)
   MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 1347, 197, 1, 1)
   Send("^v")
   Sleep(500)
   MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 495, 645, 2, 1)
   Send("^c")
   Sleep(500)
   MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 1347, 197, 1, 1)
   Send("*")
   Send("^v")
   Send("{NUMPADENTER}")
EndFunc
Func cc5()
   MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 453, 645, 2, 1)
   Send("^c")
   Sleep(500)
   MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 1347, 197, 1, 1)
   Send("^v")
   Sleep(500)
   MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 495, 645, 2, 1)
   Send("^c")
   Sleep(500)
   MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 1347, 197, 1, 1)
   Send("*")
   Send("^v")
   Send("{NUMPADENTER}")
EndFunc
Func cc6()
   MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 453, 645, 2, 1)
   Send("^c")
   Sleep(500)
   MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 1347, 197, 1, 1)
   Send("^v")
   Sleep(500)
   MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 509, 645, 2, 1)
   Send("^c")
   Sleep(500)
   MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 1347, 197, 1, 1)
   Send("*")
   Send("^v")
   Send("{NUMPADENTER}")
EndFunc
Func cc7()
   MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 453, 645, 2, 1)
   Send("^c")
   Sleep(500)
   MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 1347, 197, 1, 1)
   Send("^v")
   Sleep(500)
   MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 509, 645, 2, 1)
   Send("^c")
   Sleep(500)
   MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 1347, 197, 1, 1)
   Send("*")
   Send("^v")
   Send("{NUMPADENTER}")
EndFunc





valData()
MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 1349, 196, 1, 1) ;clicking the answer in calc
Send("^c")
Send("{DEL}")
MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 499, 706, 1, 1)
Send("^v")
Exit
```

Please help me! the output of this one is only searching for the question mark and after that is not doing anything.

Comment: Do you need to use the calculator? Autoit can do math too... Where does the question come from? You seem to copy single words from a GUI. Can't you copy the whole question and process it internally in AutoIt? That would be much faster and much more secure.

Comment: It would be great if autoit can identify worded problem like my example above. Im trying to count how many numbers in between the operator (x) by knowing the place of the question mark so when when my program identify it, it will double click the factors to copy it and do the calculation in calculator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically the same answer as `user4157124` already gave. I just broke it down to a one-liner (sacrifying the error handling; if the question doesn't match the given format, `$x` will be empty anyway).

```
ClipPut("What is 14 x 36 ?")
$x = Execute(StringRegExpReplace(ClipGet(), '^What is (\d*) x (\d*) \?$', "$1*$2"))
ConsoleWrite($x & @CRLF)
```

Also the REGEX Pattern `[^\d]*(\d+)[^\d]+(\d+).*` works (even more reliable in case there are stray spaces in or around the question)

(There is a more elegant way to get the question with `GUICtrlRead()`, but the implemention depends on how exactly the source program is built)

**EDIT** (just for troubleshooting):

As I can't see your screen, please run the following for troubleshooting:

```
MouseClick("Primary", 479, 802, 3, 10) ; slowed down to verify that the cursor goes to the right position
Send("^c")
$x = ClipGet()
ConsoleWrite('Whole question: "' & $x & '"' & @CRLF)
$x = StringRegExpReplace(ClipGet(), 'What is (\d*) x (\d*) \?$', "$1*$2")
ConsoleWrite('Math part: "' & $x & '"' & @CRLF)
$x = Execute($x)
ConsoleWrite('Result: "' & $x & '"' & @CRLF)
; MouseClick("Primary", 480, 844, 1, 1)
; Send($x)
```

Please report back the exact output from the console, so I can see, where things start to go wrong.

Comment: I think there is a problem,  1st I did try to use all of those codes that you given guys but I can make it work, when I run it ots just copying the question, 2nd maybe its my fault, because this is it, the code ```ClipPut("What is 14 x 36 ?")``` the thing is I need to copy first the question using ctrl + c, the question is something random amd changing everytime(The numbers only. So I believe i cannot use it

Comment: The `ClipPut` just puts a fix question into the clipboard for testing. You have to replace it with your method to get the actual question. We don't have your application, so we can't help you here.  (You mentioned something about triple-click, which is not optimal but will work (together with `Ctrl-C`)). The whole concept of REGEX is to extract unknown parts of a string (the two numbers in this case).

Comment: Yes I finally understand your code now and how it works, so the problem now is how I can put the answer of ```$1*$2``` to a specific text field? And to make it easier is, the way for me to go to that text field  is by click that text field using ```MouseClick```. Referencing the code that you created

Comment: Didn't you use `MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 499, 706, 1, 1)` and 
`Send("^v")` in your original code? Fill the clipboard before with `ClipPut($x)`

Comment: Code:
```MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 479, 802, 3, 1) ; Clicking all of the text
Send("^c")
MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 480, 844, 1, 1)
$x = Execute(StringRegExpReplace(ClipGet(), 'What is (\d*) x (\d*) \?$', "$1*$2"))
ClipPut($x)
Send("^v")```
Wont Return any result, now I try to edit the code
```MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 479, 802, 3, 1) ; Clicking all of the text
Send("^c")
MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 480, 844, 1, 1)
$x = StringRegExpReplace(ClipGet(), 'What is (\d*) x (\d*) \?$', "$1*$2")
ClipPut($x)
Send("^v")```
The output is ```14*36```

Comment: You forgot to `Execute()` the expression.

Comment: I dont know how Console works thou I run the code and it just copy question, I tried to click paste (ctrl+v) to the textbox to see what it will show and as what I said it only copied the question with a line break after it.

Comment: Should be easy to fix: remove the `$`(EndOfLine) from the REGEX pattern. Don't you use `Scite`? Very recommended. (Download it from the AutoIt Web site)

Comment: I do use ```Scite``` since day one, I tried to remove the end of the line ($) in the code and its just blank upon pastng

Comment: i believe this is what you are looking for:

`+>Setting Hotkeys...--> Press Ctrl+Alt+Break to Restart or Ctrl+Break to Stop
Whole question: "What is 448 x 198 ?"

Math part: "448*198"

+>16:15:20 AutoIt3.exe ended.rc:0`

Comment: Hm. The `Result: ...` part is missing. That shouldn't happen, using my code. Please double-check the code.

Comment: Yes you're right,result is missing
`+>Setting Hotkeys...--> Press Ctrl+Alt+Break to Restart or Ctrl+Break to Stop
Whole question: "What is 448 x 198 ?
"
Math part: "448*198
"
Result: ""
+>16:25:58 AutoIt3.exe ended.rc:0
+>16:25:58 AutoIt3Wrapper Finished.
>Exit code: 0    Time: 1.238`
when you figure it out please do explain it to me if its possible. Thank you

Comment: The "Math part" is correct, so there is no way for `Execute($x)` to return an empty string. Check for typos (in the Èxecute` line and the following `ConsoleWrite` line).

Comment: I tried this:
```Local $x = ClipGet()
ConsoleWrite('Whole question: "' & $x & '"' & @CRLF)
Local $x = StringRegExpReplace(ClipGet(), 'What is (\d*) x (\d*) \?$', "$1*$2")
ConsoleWrite('Math part: "' & $x & '"' & @CRLF)
Local $x = Execute("$x")
ConsoleWrite('Result: "' & $x & '"' & @CRLF)` and the result is 
` +>Setting Hotkeys...--> Press Ctrl+Alt+Break to Restart or Ctrl+Break to Stop
Whole question: "What is 448 x 198 ?
"
Math part: "448*198
"
Result: "0"
+>16:44:13 AutoIt3.exe ended.rc:0```

Comment: I'm sure, I did `Execute($x)`, not `Execute("$x")`

Comment: that is what i am trying to say, I follow the troubleshooting codes that you put there it will show "" (empty string), modifying it a bit will give me "0" result

Comment: You did `Local $x = Execute("$x")`. Remove the `Local` (because the variable `$x` already exists) `Local` should be used only once per variable (at it's very first use). And change `Execute("$x")` to `Execute($x)`, because you want to calculate the *value* of `$x`, not the *literal string* `$x`.

Comment: I will mark you answer as answered as I was able to make it work now, referencing your code. This worked for me: `$x = StringRegExpReplace(ClipGet(), 'What is (\d*) x (\d*) \?$', "$1")     $y = StringRegExpReplace(ClipGet(), 'What is (\d*) x (\d*) \?$', "$2")    $z = Execute($x*$y)    ClipPut($z) Send("^v")